# GIF output not animated

Tags: manipulate, export, gif-format

I think the current answer just creates a GIF but doesn't explain why `LocalizeVariables -> False` would cause an abnormal GIF to be exported. And I don't see any explanation about this phenomenon in the documentation. I don't sure this is a bug or not. So I hope to reopen this post.

---

Code:

```
g1 = Manipulate[Plot[{Log[x], (x^(1-a)-1)/(1-a)}, {x, 0, 5}, PlotLegends->"Expressions"], 
{a, 0, 0.99}, LocalizeVariables->False];

Export["isoelastic.gif",g1]
```

Output (GIF):

[image]

As you can see, the `.gif` is just a static image. Any ideas?

---

EDIT:

But this code worked perfectly fine:

```
a1 = Manipulate[Plot[{(1-t)*x - t*((E^(-t*x)) - 1)}, {x, -100, 100}], {t, 0, 1}]

Export["graph.gif", a1]
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: How to export without the nasty panel and controls

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because when exporting to a gif, it actually takes a list of images.  So what you actually want is

```
g1 = Table[
      Plot[{Log[x], (x^(1 - a) - 1)/(1 - a)}, {x, 0, 5}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"],
      {a, 0, 0.99, .99/100}
     ]
```

Comment: Makes sense! I've edited my question - do you know why the code snippet below worked? (I've already accepted your answer even if you don't know).

Comment: You do output the animation, but you don't explain why the op's code doesn't output the animation. I don't see anything official stating that LocalizeVariables prevents outputting animations